# iOS screen mirroring shows overscan borders on selected apps

Tags: ios, screen, mirroring, airplay, apple-tv

Problem: iPhone screen mirroring & a dedicated external view of my app show an inch of a black border on all sides.

But: Some views display perfect without black borders on the full-screen, e.g., the Apple TV menu and the photo app.

Tried already - with no effect:

- Disabled overscan on 1080p HD TV ("Disable 16:9 overscan") ( [iPad Mirroring using 2 screens, does it support 1080 resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122212/ipad-mirroring-using-2-screens-does-it-support-1080-resolution) )
- set UIScreenOverscanCompensation - has no effect ( [IOS - External (hdmi) output fills only half the screen except when coding view manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097965/ios-external-hdmi-output-fills-only-half-the-screen-except-when-coding-view) )

Setup: iPhone 4S (5.0.1), Apple TV 2nd generation (4.4.4)

Any suggestions what I could try additionally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ran into the same issue and it took a while to find the 'solution'.  Turns out you can set the overscanCompensation to '3' and it will remove the borders.

I think Apple just left out the documentation & enum for UIScreenOverscanCompensationNone, but that down in the code they check for it.

Comment: (y) Worked for me! Thanks! Indeed when I go back to the app chooser, the apple tv snaps down to "safe scan" area again, and snaps big again when my app is again forward. +1.

Comment: Setting overscanCompensation fixed the issue to an extend, but still the black borders appears when app goes to background and coming back active . My App is playing a a video in MPMovieplayer. I can reproduce the issue usually when I access some other apps (skype,notes etc) while my App in background.

Answer (score 2):

If you also have black borders during AirPlay Mirroring the answer Of MobileVet won't solve that. Try changing the following setting on your Apple TV: Settings > Audio & Video > Adjust For AirPlay Overscan. Set it to Off (default On).

And btw: doesn't 3 just mean UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds | UIScreenOverscanCompensationApplicationFrame (1 + 2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to [changes in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191134/setter-for-screen-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0/68182076#68182076) for displaying content on a connected screen, I had to set `screen.overscanCompensation = .scale` after we find the connected window scene. I noticed this after I got a message in the console, if you try to set it directly in the `.UIScreenDidConnect` notification.