# iPad 2 and 4 not mirroring/outputting video via HDMI to full screen

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay, hdmi

I am  encountering an issue which I believe is caused, as a result of upgrading to iOS version 6 on my iPad2 and iPad4. I have searched the support boards but have not found a solution to this issue. The issue involves mirroring the iPad on a TV using the official HDMI adaptor as shown here: http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD098ZM/A/apple-digital-av-adapter

When playing a video on the device using the native  MPMoviePlayerController, via the adapter, the result on the TV is not full screen and, instead, it is provided with black borders around the video (these bars are an ever present even when viewing the app's non-video parts or the standard apple menus which I believe was always the case but, previously, the video played full screen via the cable).

I have tested apps which I have developed which contain video playback, as well as a number of leading apps on the marketplace, and all experience the same issue when playing video mirrored on the device with iOS6 and TV at the same time. The only app I found that was able to play the video full screen on TV is the BBC iPlayer, but this seems to switch of mirroring off temporarily when the video is played full screen on TV.

I believe that, when on iOS 5, it was possible to mirror the video playback on device and TV simultaneously, and at full screen, without the black bars on the TV.

Can anyone here please confirm if this issue is related to iOS 6 and be able to kindly point  me in the right direction to resolve this issue in the iOS apps that I have developed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is not happening because of your external screen's `overscan` settings?

Check this thread [iOS screen mirroring shows overscan borders on selected apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465712/ios-screen-mirroring-shows-overscan-borders-on-selected-apps)

And here is some information on overscan & underscan from Apple

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5841